# CSS Multi Selector (Intersection) Not working

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, jquery-ui-multiselect

I am trying to use jquery to toggle the display property (on and off) for some classes.

I am trying to swap between an image and the text below, to toggle on click

```
<div class="fab red off">
    <img class="community_service_icon" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    <div class="community_service_text">
        Charity Run<br/>
        Charity Sale<br/>
        Bake Sale<br/>
        Photo Exhibition<br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here are my jquery functions:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.fab.red.off').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass( 'off' ).addClass( 'on' );
    $(this).children( '.community_service_icon' ).css('display', 'none');
    $(this).children( '.community_service_text' ).css('display', 'block');
  });
});

jQuery(function($) {
  $('.fab.red.on').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass( 'on' );
    $(this).addClass( 'off' );
    $(this).children( '.community_service_icon' ).css('display', 'block');
    $(this).children( '.community_service_text' ).css('display', 'none');
  });
});
```

The first click successfully hides the image and displays the text, it also changes the classes to 'fab red **on**'. However, when i click on the fab div again, it seems to run the first function with the selector '.fab.red.off' and the other function is not triggered.

Any ideas? and any suggestions to optimize this code is also much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Any particular reason you're not just using .show() and .hide()?

Comment: I was using .show and .hide, but I noticed that it was adding the css style inline, which I preferred not to do. Please correct if I am wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simplify your code using [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), which will hide the element if it is visible and show if it is not.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.fab.red').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.community_service_icon').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fab red">
  <img class="community_service_icon" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  <div class="community_service_text">
    Charity Run
    <br/>Charity Sale
    <br/>Bake Sale
    <br/>Photo Exhibition
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Common dude I didn't ask this question being a old user who holds more than 10k of reputation you should see who was the OP.

Comment: Thanks for resolving the problem and simplifying at the same time chip :)
also thanks for your support Benjamin!

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.fab.red').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('off');
});
```

```css
.off img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fab red">
  <img class="community_service_icon" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  <div class="community_service_text">Charity Run
    <br/>Charity Sale
    <br/>Bake Sale
    <br/>Photo Exhibition
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your click handler is bound "statically" once when your page is loaded; at that point there's one elements matching `.fab.red.off` selector and no elements matching `.fab.red.on`. When you change classes, event handlers are not re-bound.

jQuery `.on()` (http://api.jquery.com/on/) might be the thing you're looking for.

EDIT: Note the `selector` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.on()` function as follows [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).on('click', '.fab.red.off', function() {
    $(this).removeClass( 'off' ).addClass( 'on' );
    $(this).children( '.community_service_icon' ).css('display', 'none');
    $(this).children( '.community_service_text' ).css('display', 'block');
  });
});

jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', '.fab.red.on', function() {
    $(this).removeClass( 'on' );
    $(this).addClass( 'off' );
    $(this).children( '.community_service_icon' ).css('display', 'block');
    $(this).children( '.community_service_text' ).css('display', 'block');
  });
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y9enc8af/1/)**